# Raspberry Pi Static IP prevents WiFi from working - Connects but cannot obtain data

Tags: wifi, static-ip

I’m using a Pi4 with the latest version of Raspbian. I’m looking to set a static IP, and sure it does set, but I can’t access the internet. Can anyone assist? My dhcpcd.conf file looks like this at the bottom -

```
interface wlan0
 static ip_address=192.168.1.24/8
 static routers=192.168.0.1
 static domain_name_servers 127.0.0.1 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: In addition to my answer about Static IP Address you have provided NO diagnostics e.g. `ip a` & `ip r`. It is unlikely your WiFi isn't working, but `eth0` would have a lower metric, and be used for default routing.

Comment: Your `/8` netmask is incorrect as that includes 192.xxx.xxx.xxx addresses on the public internet. It should be `/24`. It can be anywhere between `/16` and `/24` if you really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

`static ip_address=192.168.1.24/8` is incorrect, other values are inconsistent and `static domain_name_servers 127.0.0.1` makes no sense (unless you are running a DNS)

Setting a Static IP Address is not recommended in most cases, (because so many get it wrong and it is rarely necessary) but if you want to
[How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697) explains alternatives and instructions on how to do it properly.

[How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) is a more general guide to configuring Raspbian networking.